# Switch between popup or tab browser after time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to display two different sites/Urls on a TV Display(Browser Chrome)

In case of security reasons, I can not put the content of A for eg in Site B.

My approach is now, to open website A with a button 'Start Demo'.

Site B is the first and C is the second Website. Both sould run in fullscreen Mode.

If I press the button, the should switch Site B and C after 20 seconds. Is there any example out there? Is it better, to view and control the 2 Sites in a popup?

Thank you

Comment: please show us some code so we can assist you.

Answer (score 1):

```
var newWin = window.open();

newWin.focus(); //focuses on new window

window.focus(); //focuses on main window
```